# R: get difference between increasing vectors of uneven size

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, lag, difference

I have two sequences of years, both are increasing over time. data are recorded in 5 year time step. Sometimes, between year, and event happen (NA if it does not happen). I want to know what is the **difference** between the **year** and the **nearest previous event**.

Here is my example:

```
year = seq(5,45, 5)
event = c(NA, 14,NA, NA, 29, NA, NA, NA, NA)

my.df <- data.frame(year,
                    event)
```

And expected output:

```
  year event difference
1    5    NA          0    # 0 as not previous data 
2   10    14          0    # same
3   15    NA          1    # 1 because 15-14 = 1
4   20    NA          6    # 6 because 20-14 = 6
5   25    29         11    # 11 because 25-14 = 11
6   30    NA          1    # 1 because 30-29 as the closest, not 14 anymore
7   35    NA          6    # etc
8   40    NA         11
9   45    NA         16
```

Is there somehow a way to automatize this? The events occurrence is more or less random, so I can't not just use `lag()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my.df %>% 
  mutate(event_filled_lagged = lag(event)) %>% 
  fill(event_filled_lagged) %>% 
  mutate(difference = if_else(year > event_filled_lagged, year - event_filled_lagged, NA_real_, missing = 0)) %>% 
  select(-event_filled_lagged)
```

Output

```
#   year event difference
# 1    5    NA          0
# 2   10    14          0
# 3   15    NA          1
# 4   20    NA          6
# 5   25    29         11
# 6   30    NA          1
# 7   35    NA          6
# 8   40    NA         11
# 9   45    NA         16
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution @Ric S : 1) move `event` values by one row, 2) replicate the values , 3) compare two columns and get the difference. Seems working well for this example. Do you think there is a way to make it even more versatile? (i.e. not move `even` by exactly by one row)  but instead always relate `year` to the nearest value in `event`? Thank you again!

Comment: @maycca It depends on whether your goals are. For instance, what do you mean by "relate `year` to the nearest value in `event`"?

Comment: Actually, I realized that this perfectly answers my questions. Thanks!